# Kitchen Cabinet Wear Mark repair

Tags: wood

Kitchen Cabinet Wear Mar Repair

Hello

I’m trying to repair a couple of my kitchen cabinets which have some wear marks on it (as shown in the first picture). I’m not looking to stain or to paint the cabinets as it’s only a few of them.

I was cleaning them with some mineral oil and it got rid of the scratch marks exactly how I’d like but the effect isn’t permanent.

Do you know of any product which does this in a permanent way and is protective against wear and tear?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Pic didn't work...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please review your post after you submit it ... do not assume that all pictures are there and that there are no errors